# How to wire path/chart redraw after y domain changes

Tags: d3.js

I want to draw multiple barcharts into the same visualization.

When the first barchart is drawn it ḱnows nothing about the domain of the 2nd, 3rd, etc. At the time the 2nd barchart is drawn the domain of the y scale changes. 'Consequently the first barchart needs to be redrawn. The question is what is a good way to wire up the redraw since the scale/domain has no change notification mechanism.

http://bl.ocks.org/markfink/4d8f1c183e6cd9d6ea07

Comment: Why do you need an event here? You can redraw the first chart when you draw the second one etc.

Comment: this is only a simplified gist to demonstrate the problem. The whole thing is here: http://bl.ocks.org/markfink/e1db605d50d199339c14. All chats need to be independent - only the zoomer takes care for the redraws. Question is how does the zoomer handle the redraw occasions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/tBHyD/2/

I only tried to address the setup in the question, not the full implementation noted in your comment. There are lots of ways to accomplish this; this one uses an event-driven model, using `d3.dispatch`:

```
    var evt = d3.dispatch("change");
```

The key here is to update the scale extents globally, then fire an event if they've changed. Here I use a function, `updateExtent`, for this purpose:

```
    var x0 = Infinity,
        x1 = -Infinity,
        y0 = Infinity,
        y1 = -Infinity;
    function updateExtent(data) {
        var extx = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[0]; }),
            exty = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[1]; }),
            changed;
        // update
        if (extx[0] < x0) { x0 = extx[0]; changed = true; }
        if (extx[1] > x1) { x1 = extx[1]; changed = true; }
        if (exty[0] < y0) { y0 = exty[0]; changed = true; }
        if (exty[1] > y1) { y1 = exty[1]; changed = true; }
        // if changed, update scales and fire event
        if (changed) {
            // update scales
            x.domain([x0, x1]);
            y.domain([y1, y0]);
            // update axes
            vis.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
            vis.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
            // fire event
            evt.change();
        }
    }
```

Then the `redraw` function sets a listener:

```
    function redraw(selection, data, style) {
        var bar = selection.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data);

        // enter
        bar.enter().append("rect")
            .attr('class', "bar")
            .attr("width", 5)
            .style(style);

        function updateBar() {
            // update
            bar
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]) - .5; })
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d[1]);  });
        }
        // initial call
        updateBar();
        // handler call
        evt.on("change", updateBar);
    };
```

Note that now you don't need to set the extent explicitly:

```
    var data1 = [[2,0.5], [4,0.8], [6,0.6], [8,0.7], [12,0.8]];
    updateExtent(data1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer! I did not know about d3.dispatch - this is exactly what I was looking for and the code is much more concise now. This stuff is not covered in the introductory book by Murray. Is there something you recommend that covers the "advanced" topics?

Comment: The API docs :). Seriously, though, I don't know if there's a D3 book that would cover evented models, as I haven't seen many examples that use this; `d3.dispatch` is listed under "Internals" in the API. It's not a bad architecture for coordinating components, though.